# SELECT all if parameter is null else return specfic item laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5.5

i'm planned to create a Filter. if a parameter is null return all else return specific item.

```
title = "A" and body="B"  --> return all values where title like A & body like B
title = "" and body="B"  -->  return all values where body like B
title = "" and body=""  -->  return all values
```

this is my query how to change this query according to my criteria

```
$posts =  Blog::where('title','LIKE',"%{$title}%")
            ->Where('body', 'LIKE',"%{$body}%")
            ->offset($start)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy($order,$dir)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query builder object according to your criteria

```
$posts =  Blog::offset($start)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy($order,$dir);
if(!empty($title)){
    $posts = $posts->where('title','LIKE',"%{$title}%");
}

if(!empty($body)){
    $posts = $posts->where('body','LIKE',"%{$body}%");
}           
$posts = $posts->get();
```